# Searching for text while in insert mode of Neovim

Tags: neovim, search, insert-mode

I know how to search for text in visual mode in Vim/Neovim. However, I find it unnecessary when I am in insert mode to have to exit it, search and then come back to insert mode.

Is there a way to conduct search in the insert mode (without exiting it)?

Comment: Please try to get used to a modal editor and its concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While is insert mode you can use the <kbd>Ctrl o</kbd> to escape for one action and automatically come back to insert mode right after.

<kbd>Ctrl o</kbd>`/foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd> move the cursor to the next occurrence of `foo` but stay in insert mode.

<kbd>Ctrl o</kbd>`n` move the cursor to the next occurrence of the previous search.

You can add insert mode mapping to ease the access to the trick:

```
" Ctrl-f to search for the next occurrence
inoremap <C-f> <C-o>/
" Ctrl-r to search for the previous occurrence
inoremap <C-r> <C-o>?
```

Remark: It is probably not very wise to override <kbd>Ctrl r</kbd> since <kbd>Ctrl r</kbd>`*` is used to paste the system clipboard (the `*` register) in insert mode (`:help i_CTRL-R`).

Remark: <kbd>Ctrl f</kbd> is used in insert mode to re-indent the line in insert mode (`:help i_CTRL-F`)

Comment: Thanks! So, perhaps, it should be possible to tie this to a single key stroke (such as Ctrl-F in insert mode to the search for a string?) Also, the reverse search could be done with Ctrl-R?

Comment: @user3236841 you could, but then you lose the useful default functionality of those keys in Insert mode. I recommend trying to get used to being in Normal mode most of the time.

Comment: I have added the proposed shortcuts for the sake of Vim/Neovim demonstration configurability :-)

Comment: I'd suggest to try to use Vim like it was meant to be used, e.g. make use of different modes and don't try to convert it to something totally different. `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-R` in insert mode already have a meaning, which you will lose if you map to it.

Comment: thanks, @VivianDeSmedt! Nice demo.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks! OK, I did not realize that these were already mapped. I will try something else. Though I also feel that one of the key efficiencies is by having some common keybindings across applications, especailly for long-time users of something else like me. I don't feel dogmatic about things, as long as clarity can be maintained.

Comment: thank you @ChristianBrabandt, also. Since stack does not allow for multiple acknowledgements, they have to be done separately.

Comment: Perhaps I can use Ctrl-F and Ctrl-R (or Alt-F and Alt-R)? Btw, how can I do the same but use Ctrl-F or Alt-F to keep on searching the previously entered word (therefore ctrl-o n unless a word is entered?

Comment: The code for Alt-f is <M-f>. I'm not sure I understand correctly your question about à previously entered word. Maybe could ask another question and give an example.